# Declare a variable and then set to a data type?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

Accidental DBA, here. I'm looking at a query that was written by a past DBA who is no longer with the company and I noticed something that I consider to be odd; maybe I'm just ignorant. The SQL is used to gather information about the DBs and provide hyperlinks and file locations. It uses one variable. Below is the bit of code in question and it is the very beginning of the query.

```
 declare @crlf varchar(2)
 set @crlf = char(13)+char(10)
```

So, to me, it looks like the variable is declared as varchar, but is then set as a concatenation of two char data types? This is confusing to me because:

A) why would he not just set the variable as the data type he wants to begin with? 
B) I didn't realize you could SET a variable to a data type and not a value
C) I also didn't know you could concatenate (or add in this case, maybe?) data types together. This just makes no sense to me at all.

Any insight on this?

Comment: A) because he doesn't really know what he's doing. B) there is a data precedence docs where it explains how this conversions work. C) the `CHAR(n)` function returns a single char as a result, it's not "concatenating data types"

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. I just assumed that char(n) was a data type that  is fixed-length vs. varchar, which isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is simply setting this to a carriage return (CR) and new line feed (LF) hence the variable name `crlf`. You could use the same method to set it to two letters...

```
 declare @crlf varchar(2)
 set @crlf = char(88)+char(89)

 select @crlf
```

**RESULTS**

```
XY
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is calling the `CHAR()` function versus assigning a data type which would be a string literal. The opposite would be the `ASCII()` function.

[Reference ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)